# Can I have a custom way to resolve conflicts in `Array#to_h`?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have something like `list = [[:a, 1], [:b, 1], [:a, 2]]`. I want to turn this into `{a: 3, b: 1}`.

I feel like I should be able to do this just by doing `list.to_h(:+)` but that doesn't seem possible. I could of course use `reduce`, but that seems unnecessarily complex.

Is there a simpler way to do this? For example, if I was using Haskell I could do `Map.fromListWith (+)` for this functionality.

Comment: This question does not make sense, can you show us a minimum working code and then say why you think its complex.  Once you do `list.to_h`, it will return `{:a=>2, :b=>1}`, from which you will never be able to arrive at desired output

Comment: @Wand I don't understand. Of course it doesn't work how I want it to, that's why I have a question? For example, in Haskell I can do `Map.fromListWith`and I want to know how to do this in Ruby.

Comment: @Xodarap But your questions asks for answer that does not "seems unnecessarily complex" - how will one decide whether a solution is complex or not - the perspective of complexity is different from person to person

Comment: @Wand: letting me know the name of a gem which expands `to_h` in the way that I want is a very clear, non-subjective answer, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who want to do this, here is a patch:

```
class Array
  def to_h(&block)
    return super unless block

    each_with_object(Hash.new) do |(key, value), memo|
      if memo.key?(key)
        memo[key] = block.call(memo[key], value)
      else
        memo[key] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it like `puts [[:a, 1], [:b, 1], [:a, 2]].to_h(&:+)`

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem possible since `to_h` doesn't take arguments. Why do you think it's unnecessarily complex to use `each_with_object` or `reduce`?

```
[[:a, 1], [:b, 1], [:a, 2]].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k, v), memo| 
  memo[k] += v
end
```

That seems straight forward to me

Comment: @WandMaker I missed the argument to `each_with_object`. I've updated the answer but that doesn't take away from my point

Comment: That's just a complicated way to raise a NoMethodError, `each_with_object(Hash.new(0))` OTOH...

Comment: Yeah, I get that I can use `each_with_object` (or `reduce`, as I mentioned) but this seems unnecessarily verbose. I updated the question to point out that Haskell has a way to do this

Comment: That another language allows doing something differently doesn't really matter. Ruby does it as Matz designed. We work with how he designed it using the given tools. It's just one of those "that's how it is" things when dealing with multiple languages.

Comment: The example isn't quite correct. Using `{}` will return "undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass". Instead use `each_with_object(Hash.new(0))`.

Comment: @Xodarap if you wanted that kind of functionality you could always write your own method that does what you want and abstract the complexity out. At the end of the day that's probably what Haskell is doing by providing that function. Just because Ruby doesn't provide it doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: @Leo: sure, I just wanted to know if it already existed in some Ruby gem